# str_join() function, not present in the standard C library

Tags: c, strings, library

This function `str_join()` is an updated version of my earlier function `strcat_new()` — found here: [`strcat_new()` function, not present in the Standard C library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270524/strcat-new-function-not-present-in-standard-c-library).

The older version `strcat_new()` had a bug that is fixed in this version of `str_join()`.

Syntax: `char *str_join(const char *delim, long num_args, ...);`

---

### str_join.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include "str_join.h"

/* 
 * str_join:
 *
 * Parameters:
 *      num_args: number of variable arguments that are passed to this function
 *                excluding the 'delim' string.
 *      ...: Variable number of pointers to character arrays.
 *
 * Description:
 *      str_join concatenates all the strings/character arrays passed to it. If
 *      'delim' is not NULL then after every string, the 'delim' string is concatenated.
 *      It allocates a new character array whose size is equal to the sum of the
 *      lengths of all strings passed to it plus 1 (extra 1 for terminating null byte).
 *      It then concatenates all the strings passed to it separated by 'delim' string
 *      into the newly allocated character array and then returns the pointer to
 *      the newly allocated character array. If memory allocation fails then NULL is returned.
 *
 *      It is the responsibility of the caller to free the allocated memory.
 */
char *str_join(const char *delim, long num_args, ...)
{

    va_list valist;
    long i = 0;
    long j = 0;
    long iica = 0; // iica - index into character array
    long len = 0;
    long delim_len = 0;
    long total_len = 0;
    long num_delim_to_concat = -1;
    char *new_char_array = NULL;
    char *temp = NULL;
    
    if (num_args <= 0)
        return NULL;

    if (delim) {
        delim_len = strlen(delim);
    }
    
    va_start(valist, num_args);
    for (i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
        temp = va_arg(valist, char *);
        if (!temp) continue;
        total_len = total_len + strlen(temp);
        num_delim_to_concat = num_delim_to_concat + 1;
    }
    va_end(valist);

    if (total_len == 0)
        return NULL;

    total_len = total_len + (num_delim_to_concat) * (delim_len);
    total_len = total_len + 1; // 1 extra for terminating null byte

    new_char_array = malloc(total_len);
    if (!new_char_array)
        return NULL;

    va_start(valist, num_args);
    for (i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
        temp = va_arg(valist, char *);
        if (!temp) continue;
        len = strlen(temp);
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            new_char_array[iica] = temp[j];
            iica++;
        }
        if (num_delim_to_concat > 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < delim_len; j++) {
                new_char_array[iica] = delim[j];
                iica++;
            }
            num_delim_to_concat = num_delim_to_concat - 1;
        }
    }
    va_end(valist);

    new_char_array[iica] = 0;

    return new_char_array;

} // end of str_join
```

---

### str_join.h

```
#ifndef _STRCAT_NEW_H_
#define _STRCAT_NEW_H_

/* 
 * str_join:
 *
 * Parameters:
 *      num_args: number of variable arguments that are passed to this function
 *                excluding the 'delim' string.
 *      ...: Variable number of pointers to character arrays.
 *
 * Description:
 *      str_join concatenates all the strings/character arrays passed to it. If
 *      'delim' is not NULL then after every string, the 'delim' string is concatenated.
 *      It allocates a new character array whose size is equal to the sum of the
 *      lengths of all strings passed to it plus 1 (extra 1 for terminating null byte).
 *      It then concatenates all the strings passed to it separated by 'delim' string
 *      into the newly allocated character array and then returns the pointer to
 *      the newly allocated character array. If memory allocation fails then NULL is returned.
 *
 *      It is the responsibility of the caller to free the allocated memory.
 */
char *str_join(const char *delim, long num_args, ...);

#endif
```

---

### test_str_join.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "str_join.h"

int main(void)
{

    char *a = str_join(";:?", 4, "abc", "123", "xyz", "455");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, strlen(a));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(NULL, 3, "123", "xyz", "455");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, strlen(a));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(NULL, 0, "123", "xyz", "455");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, a?strlen(a):(unsigned long)(-1));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(NULL, -1, "123", "xyz", "455");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, a?strlen(a):(unsigned long)(-1));
    free(a);

    a = str_join("=", 4, "abc", "123", "xyz", "455");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, strlen(a));
    free(a);

    a = str_join("{(=%$^%^&&(&)}", 4, "abc", "123", "xyz", "455");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, strlen(a));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(";;;", 4, "abc", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, strlen(a));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(";;;", 4, "abc", NULL, NULL, "cde");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, strlen(a));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(NULL, 4, NULL, "fdr", NULL, NULL);
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, a?strlen(a):(unsigned long)(-1));
    free(a);

    a = str_join("-------", 10, "START", "hfjkdhf78578695590", "nvmcnkjfhgkjfh^&*^&*", "7856475947584", "!@^&^%#*&(*$&(&$(*", "j", "4", "khfkjhgiury6985768956uirhtukrhgkhfk", "jfjlkjgk65876895769576895khgkjfkkhkjhjG%^&%#*@^*@^$*&^#&$*#$#*$&#$&$(*#", "END");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, a?strlen(a):(unsigned long)(-1));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(NULL, 1, NULL, "fdr", NULL, NULL);
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, a?strlen(a):(unsigned long)(-1));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(";", 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, "xyz");
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, a?strlen(a):(unsigned long)(-1));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(";;;", 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, a?strlen(a):(unsigned long)(-1));
    free(a);

    a = str_join(NULL, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    printf("\n");
    printf("a = %s, strlen(a) = %lu\n", a, a?strlen(a):(unsigned long)(-1));
    free(a);

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Just a little tip for improvement: create a more generic version of the function - one that accepts a malloc-like function pointer. Then the str_join itself would just call it passing malloc as the function pointer. This will allow you to test the inner function against a custom malloc implementation and you can actually test whether the right amount of memory is allocated.

Comment: (If you intentionally restrict the code to C89, please tag accordingly.)

Comment: @greybeard Must be at least C99, as no `return 0;` in `main()`.

Comment: What's wrong with using [snprintf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065286/snprintf-for-string-concatenation) to join strings?

Answer (score 4):

**No test reference**

There are no tests in `test_str_join.c`, just code being exercised.  How is the *test* to detect if output is correct? If by visual inspection, including comments of expected output would at least be a good start.

**Undefined behavior printing a *null pointer***

Example: last test may print `a = (null), strlen(a) = 18446744073709551615` or crash or ...  It is UB.

**`NULL` is not safe as a `...` argument**

The type of `NULL` is `void *`, `int`, `long`, *some integer type*.  It is not safe to fetch via `va_arg(valist, char *)`.

Better test code would use `(void *) NULL`, `(void *) 0`.

**Wrong type**

Types used for string length are as if `long` and `size_t` were the similar types.  `size_t` is the type returned by `strlen()` and the type used in allocations.  `size_t` is the Goldilocks type for array indexing, neither too narrow nor too wide.  `long` is *signed*, `size_t` is *unsigned*.  `LONG_MAX` may be less than or more than (or even the same as) `SIZE_MAX`.  `long` usage here [remains](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270531/29485) questionable.

If you want to remain with `long`, use `len = (long) strlen(temp);` to quiet warnings like :

```
warning: conversion to 'size_t' from 'long int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
```

**Why delimiter after last?**

Goal is "after every string, the 'delim' string is concatenated".   Then later says "separated by 'delim' string".  This code apparently only delimits between strings. Comments need revision for consistency.

**Zero `num_args`**

I still [maintain](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270531/29485) a return of allocated `""` is expected for `char *str_join(",", 0)` rather than `NULL` of this code.

**Repeated comments**

*Parameters:* and *Description:* are repeated in the *.c and *.h files.  Once is enough - best in the .h file.  Consider code maintenance is more expensive that original code writing and maintaining same comments in 2 files is additional unnecessary work - likely to diverge over time.

**Print formed string with sentinels**

Easier to identify unexpected leading and trailing white-space.

```
// printf("a = %s ...
printf("a = \"%s\" ...
```

**Simplify**

To code a `(unsigned long)(-1)`, easy to use `-1UL`.

**Define when needed**

Rather than define an object far from its use and at a higher scope than needed:

```
//char *temp = NULL;
//... 8 lines
//for (i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
//    temp = va_arg(valist, char *);
//    if (!temp) continue;
//    total_len = total_len + strlen(temp);

for (i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
    char *temp = va_arg(valist, char *);
    if (!temp) continue;
    total_len = total_len + strlen(temp);
```

**Minor: avoid `!`**

I have found less misunderstandings when `!`, `!=` are avoided.  Consider alternatives.

```
// if (!temp) continue;
if (temp == NULL) continue;
```

**2nd posting without finishing first.**

Consider wrapping up [earlier](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/270524/29485) related questions before posing an updated question.

[*unfinished* before *new*](http://www.jimslaughter.com/Order-of-Business-for-Meetings-.cfm) business.

Comment: Maybe add: Contradictory description: Is `delim` inserted between any two, or after every single argument...

Comment: @Deduplicator Nice alternative way to say it.  Issue brought up [before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270531/29485). Unclear if OP wants to address it.

Comment: I will fix the description. Basically, the delim is between valid (non-null and non-empty) strings (arguments). I also need to fix the empty string(s) case - if the user passes empty string(s) then these empty string(s) will not be concatenated/joined and will be ignored.

Comment: Chux, on your comment: `Undefined behavior printing a null pointer` - how will it crash? How is it unbounded?

Comment: Chux, `NULL is not safe as a ... argument`: I already gave my comments on this in the review comments of strcat_new().

Comment: Chux, `Zero num_args`: I already gave my comments on this in the review comments of strcat_new().

Comment: Chux, `Define when needed`: I already gave my comments on this in the review comments of strcat_new().

Comment: Chux, `Minor: avoid !`: I got a review comment in some other posting to avoid (temp == NULL) and use !temp. So, this is a subjective issue. Personally, I prefer `!temp` but sometimes I use `temp == NULL` also.

Comment: @Amit, re "Undefined behavior printing a null pointer - how will it crash? How is it unbounded?" to attempt to use `"%s"` with an invalid pointer -- it is _undefined_ (UB),  there is no prescribed way it will crash - it is not defined.  It might "work", it might crash in various ways.  If you still want to print something reliable when `s == NULL`, instead of `printf("%s\n", s);` use `printf("%s\n", s ? s : "null");`

Comment: Ok. On my system this doesn't crash. I am using gcc. But its quite possible that it may crash on some other C compiler or some other C library which doesn't handle NULL values in printf.

Comment: Chux, on cygwin, I am doing long x = strlen("abcde"); and am using the flags mentioned above when compiling. But I don't get any warning about sign change. The flags that I use are: -Wall, -Werror, -Wextra, -Wundef, -Wunreachable-code, -Winit-self, -Wparentheses, -Wconversion, -Wsign-conversion, -Wsign-compare, -Werror-implicit-function-declaration, -Wmissing-prototypes, -Wmissing-declarations, -Wformat-security.

Comment: @Amit Hmmm,  compiler is smart and sees `strlen("abcde")` is 5 and knows that `long` is not an issue.  Try a non-fixed string.  `long foo(char *s) { return strlen(s); }`

Comment: I ran the same code on a linux system and I got the sign conversion warning. It looks like gcc on cygwin hasn't implemented the sign conversion flag(s) in gcc.

Answer (score 1):

The macro name `_STRCAT_NEW_H_` is an identifier reserved for any purpose by the implementation.  Do not use identifiers beginning with `_` in your own code.

Always include your defining header first in your implementation file, before standard headers.  This can help identify accidental dependencies (i.e. creating a header that's not self-sufficient).

Many of the variables have much larger scope than necessary.  Reduce scope, and delay declaration to where the variable can be initialised.

Avoid using signed types where unsigned makes more sense.  For example, `num_args` should be a `size_t`, or possibly `unsigned` given that we should not be passing 65536 or more arguments in a function call.  Certainly the "length" accumulators should be `size_t`.

The local variables for the argument strings should be `const char*`, because callers should be able to pass non-writable strings.

Don't return a null pointer when the result is an empty string - that just makes life difficult for the caller, and makes it impossible to tell whether the function was successful or not.  Be careful that `num_delim_to_concat` doesn't remain at -1 in that case, though.

Consider splitting out a function that accepts a `va_list` argument (ala `vsprintf()`) so that calling code is able to forward argument lists.  You'll find this useful for the tests, too.

Use standard functions (`strcat`/`strcpy`/`memcpy`) for writing to the output string, instead of hand-rolling loops.  A decent optimising compiler will likely generate the same code for both, but at less risk of programmer error.

Prefer idiomatic increment - e.g. `--num_delim_to_concat` rather than `num_delim_to_concat = num_delim_to_concat - 1`, and `total_len += num_delim_to_concat * delim_len` rather than `total_len = total_len + (num_delim_to_concat) * (delim_len)`.  Writing these out longhand leaves the reader wondering what's going on.

The tests are repetitive, which suggests that a helper function may be valuable.  Also, instead of being self-checking, they require manual inspection, which is time-consuming and error-prone.  Rewrite so that the exit status indicates whether the tests passed or not.

Tests pass `NULL` as a vararg parameter.  This needs to be cast to `char*` to be safely transferred.

Tests should help demonstrate how the code is to be used.  Therefore, they should test whether a null pointer was returned, rather than assuming a valid object pointer.

Comment: Toby, about `Many of the variables have much larger scope than necessary`: I don't like "define/declare variables when needed". This way my variables would be scattered all across the function. I want all my variables at the top - I feel comfortable doing this. Scattering my variables all across the function doesn't make me feel comfortable. All the places I worked (I worked mostly in C), there was no guideline to follow "define/declare when needed". I have seen lots and lots of active C production code which does not follow "define/declare when needed" approach.

Comment: Toby, size_t vs long is debatable/personal preference. I like long instead of size_t. I have no problem if someone doesn't want to use my code because of this.

Comment: Another downside to declaring all variables at start of function scope is the risk of use before assignment.  It's possible that the the "lots of production code" was written prior to 1999, when declarations couldn't be intermixed with statements.  Using `long` instead of `size_t` is just wrong (both in range and signedness), and the resulting warnings can obscure other problems in your code (and if you're not getting warnings, you really should be enabling them).

Comment: There is no risk of use before assignment because variables should be initialized at the time of declaration.

Comment: The lots of production code that I saw (that didn't use define/declare when needed) was as late as 2020.

Comment: The flags that I use are: -Wall, -Werror, -Wextra, -Wundef, -Wunreachable-code, -Winit-self, -Wparentheses, -Wconversion, -Wsign-conversion, -Wsign-compare, -Werror-implicit-function-declaration, -Wmissing-prototypes, -Wmissing-declarations, -Wformat-security.

Comment: On cygwin, I am doing `long x = strlen("abcde");` and am using the flags mentioned above when compiling. But I don't get any warning about sign change.

Comment: See this code of Redis (they are also not doing define/declare when needed): https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/2.2/src/replication.c

Comment: I don't like shorthand operators because of the following reason. Let's say that there is `x += 1`. Now, if by mistake "+" gets deleted then it becomes `x = 1`. So, the problem with shorthand operators is that if by mistake some character(s) get deleted, the expression changes and there will be no compiler warnings. Now, let's consider `x = x + 1`, here if "+" gets deleted by mistake then it becomes `x = x 1` and then compiler will generate a warning and we can fix it then.

Comment: `Don't return a null pointer when the result is an empty string`: I didn't understand where is this happening. Can you please give an example?

Comment: I think I got it from `str_join("", 1, (char*)0)`.

Comment: Since you are passing a NULL string, there is nothing to join. So, the result is NULL.

Comment: Well, that's surprising.  If we join nothing, then I'd expect an empty string, the same as when we multiply nothing (e.g. 0!) we get `1` (multiplicative identity).  I'm sure that's a design choice, but it may well trip up your users.  It does make that case impossible to distinguish from the "failed operation" case (e.g. couldn't allocate memory).

Comment: Actually, now I am thinking to process NULL strings and EMPTY strings as normal strings. So, if a user gives two string arguments (and both are NULL), then the resulting string will have delimiter only. This idea came when I thought about user getting string values from somewhere (database, etc.) and the user wants to write those values in a file. So, in case the string is NULL or EMPTY then only the delimiter will be copied in the resulting string. I will post next version of str_join() after some days.

Comment: With two null arguments, shouldn't there be no delimiter?  One string and one null, doesn't get a delimiter, so why should two nulls?  Whatever you decide, having a good think about the interface will certainly repay the effort you put in!

Comment: Since all strings will be treated as valid strings (NULL and empty strings also), so between two strings there will be one delimiter.

Comment: I think I will let the user to tell the function whether to ignore NULL / EMPTY strings or not. An extra argument will be there in the str_join() function - `unsigned int ignore_null_and_empty_strings`.

Comment: Probably better to pass as a bit set in `unsigned int flags`, in case you want to add more options later.